# Docker with magento how to apply file changes to frontend

Tags: magento2, docker

I have setup magento with [This Github repo](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento#misc-info) but when changing `pub/index.php` with exit command it won't affect untill i push this to container.So my question is that everytime when i create file or remove file or modify any file i have to push my changes to container to get it affect on my frontend.

Can anybody please guide me how to working with magento local change when using docker?

Comment: That is cache issue. Clear cache.

Comment: Thanks sohel but it's not cache issue i come to know that we have to map volume for this but still need more specific answer on this

Comment: How to use this docker for development purpose.